# Can Google Lens or other app translate separate words or phrases rather than whole sentences

Tags: translate

I need to translate puzzles/exercises where one need to insert missing words, translating sentences result in rubbish.

I think translating texts word by word could be more useful.

Is it doable with Android device? Perhaps, Google Lens or other app can be configure to translate separate words or phrases individually rather than whole sentences?

I think one solution could be apply OCR, copy text and ask chatGPT translate word by word. Are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible because there's no such setting in any translating app. Translating a partial sentence often results in inaccurate and even absurd translation when translated to another language that's why it's not practical.

The only thing you can do is scan the first half before the blank and then the other half, sacrificing your accuracy and any hope of solving the puzzle (kidding, this should help since human is but the best AI. Goodluck)